# php Extends three class without interface

Tags: php, oop

I have three class , called `A`,`B`,`C` and another class called `X`.

In this `X` class I want to access a few function from `A`, `B` and `C`.

I know if I want to access the function in one class, I can use:

```
class X extends A { ... }
```

Now I can access all `A` public functions, but now I want to access the `B` and `C` class functions as well.

How do I access methods from `B` and `C` from within `X`?

Comment: Inheritance provides you with more than access to `A`'s public methods, which are available without inheritance. You also gain access to any protected methods/members of `A`, which is the real reason for inheritance.

Answer (score 4):

the only way without interface is

```
class A extends B {}
class B extends C {}
class x extends A {}
```

There is no multiple inheritance in PHP

Answer (score 2):

If you're only looking to access the public functions, you might consider rethinking your architecture to use composition instead of inheritance. Tie together your three classes into one class which uses them:

```
class X {
  private $a, $b, $c;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->a = new A();
    $this->b = new B();
    $this->c = new C();
  }

  function do_stuff() {
    $this->a->do_a_stuff();
    $this->b->do_b_stuff();
    $this->c->do_c_stuff();
  }

}
```

Comment: can also provide the magic `__call` method to autoproxy method calls to the other instances. that would be kinda slow though because you'll have to check which instance is the right one. On the other hand, this would allow you to define your own rules for the diamond problem. But of course, you could just as well write the appropriate proxy methods on X.

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not support multiple inheritance. You can use Composition anyway.